# Skip functions in shell script with command line arguments

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have written shell script with different functions, that I can invoke from the command line like so:

`bash script.sh -i -b`

So that will run those two functions and not the other ones in the script. However, I want to reverse this logic, by have the script run every function by default if I just do

`bash script.sh`

And if I pass arguments like `-i -b` I would like to skip over those functions instead. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check `getopts` in bash over google

Comment: You need to detect that no arguments are processed by getopts and implement your logic from there. Check this [Unix StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50563/how-can-i-detect-that-no-options-were-passed-with-getopts). If you don't want to inspect getopts behavior, you can simply check if `[ $# -eq 0 ]` .

Comment: See _manual loop_ section of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: @AlexandreJuma how do I skip over functions through command line args?

Comment: Check the new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement those the two logics:

1. If no arguments at all, run all functions
2. For each argument passed, skip some function execution

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function func_i {
  echo "I am i."
}

function func_b {
  echo "I am b."
}

function main {

  # Check if there are no arguments, run all functions and exit.

  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    func_i
    func_b
    exit 0
  fi

  # Parse arguments -i and -b, marking them for no execution if they are passed to the script.

  proc_i=true
  proc_b=true

  while getopts "ib" OPTION; do
      case $OPTION in
      i)
          proc_i=false
          ;;
      b)
          proc_b=false
          ;;
      *)
          echo "Incorrect options provided"
          exit 1
          ;;
      esac
  done

  # Execute whatever function is marked for run.

  if $proc_i; then func_i; fi
  if $proc_b; then func_b; fi
}

main "$@"
```

Some explanations:

`$#` returns the number of arguments passed to the script. If `$#` is equal to 0, then no arguments were passed to the script.

`getops` accepts switches `-i` and `-b`, all other switches will result in error handled in the `*)` case.

Comment: I haven't implemented `getopts` to my script, it's just simple functions and calling them through command line. New to bash scripts so a bit more detail would be appreciated!

Comment: This solves the problem of running all the functions, but what if I want to skip a specific part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You could black list items from the list of functions that are called by default.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

list='a b c d e f g h i'

# define some functions
for name in $list; do
        eval "func_$name() { echo func_$name called with arg \$1; }"
done

# black list items from list
for x; do
        list=$(echo "$list" | tr -d ${x#-})
done

for name in $list; do
        func_$name $name
done
```

But frankly it makes more sense to do something like:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

list='a b c d e f g h i'
test $# = 0 && set -- $list # set default list of functions to call

# define some function
for name in $list; do
        eval "func_$name() { echo func_$name called with arg \$1; }"
done

for name; do
        func_$name $name
done
$ bash ./script.sh 
func_a called with arg a
func_b called with arg b
func_c called with arg c
func_d called with arg d
func_e called with arg e
func_f called with arg f
func_g called with arg g
func_h called with arg h
func_i called with arg i
$ bash ./script.sh c g
func_c called with arg c
func_g called with arg g
```